# How do I retrieve data from s SharePoint list using JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint

I am new to SharePoint and I am trying to read-in the data from a SharePoint list using JavaScript. I created a new SP page and inserted a content editor web part. In the content editor I inserted the following code. When I click save I see the code itself but not the contents from the SP lists. How do I read in data from a SP list using JS?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
<script>
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';

function retrieveListItems() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemInfo = '';

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
            '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + 
            '\nBody: ' + oListItem.get_item('Body');
    }

    document.write(listItemInfo.toString());
    //alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        //var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';

        function retrieveListItems() {
            //get current site context
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();//SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
            var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Test');

            var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' +
                '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
            this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

            clientContext.load(collListItem);

            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

        }

        function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

            var listItemInfo = '';

            var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

            while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() +
                    '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') +
                    '\nBody: ' + oListItem.get_item('Country');// custom field
            }

            //document.write(listItemInfo.toString());
            document.getElementById("DataResult").innerHTML = listItemInfo;
            //alert(listItemInfo.toString());
        }

        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
    </script>
    <div id="DataResult">

    </div>
    <input id="Button1" onclick="retrieveListItems()" type="button" value="retrieveListItems" />
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

[image]

[You could bind data to jQuery datatable](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-jquery-datatable-to-display-sharepoint-list-data-on-share/)

Comment: Lee_MSFT thanks for the feedback. But, I still a page with all the code showing. Are doing something in addition to adding the code to the Content Editor?

Comment: Never mind my previous comment. I see I had to first click "embed code" and then put my code there. Now I see the button. Thanks. BTW, what is the parameter being passed to getByTitle called Test? Is that the page I'm trying to read from?

Comment: 'Test' is list title which you get data from.